# removing few columns from data table C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I need to remove few columns from datatable and bind to grid view. So I tried below code:

```
        obj_dt = obj_backup.sale_where_date();

        grd_excel.DataSource = obj_dt;

        obj_dt_pdf = obj_dt;

        // to remove few columns in data table 

        obj_dt_pdf.Columns.Remove("Location");
        obj_dt_pdf.Columns.Remove("No Opn Stack");
        obj_dt_pdf.Columns.Remove("Expiry Date");
        obj_dt_pdf.Columns.Remove("Discount %");
        obj_dt_pdf.Columns.Remove("Discount Amt");
        obj_dt_pdf.Columns.Remove("TAX");
        obj_dt_pdf.Columns.Remove("VAT");
        obj_dt_pdf.Columns.Remove("Entry Date");

        dataGridView_wd_pdf.DataSource = obj_dt_pdf;
```

Problem is after removing columns in obj_dt_pdf its also removing from obj_dt. I need to remove in obj_dt_pdf alone.
where I made error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are assigning `obj_dt` to `obj_dt_pdf` you are not copying `DataTable` - you just make copy of reference to `DataTable` instance. So, that makes both variables point to same `DataTable` instance:

```
obj_dt_pdf = obj_dt;
```

Create copy of DataTable instead (use [DataTable.Copy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to copy both table structure and data):

```
obj_dt_pdf = obj_dt.Copy();
```

Now `obj_dt_pdf` points to copy of original `DataTable`, and changes of copy will not affect original `DataTable` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Then don't use the same reference. You can use [`Clone`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get a `DataTable` with the same schema of a table (without data) or [`Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create a clone with all data:

```
obj_dt = obj_backup.sale_where_date();
var copy = obj_dt.Copy();
copy.Columns.Remove("Location");
copy.Columns.Remove("No Opn Stack");
// ...
dataGridView_wd_pdf.DataSource = copy;
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataTable` is a class, and classes are "reference types", this means that when you assign it to another variable you just have two variables pointing to the same instance.

You would need to create a "copy" of the object, and lucky for you it just so happens that `DataTable` has a [`Copy()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so you can do this:

```
obj_dt_pdf = obj_dt.Copy();
```

**Do not** get this confused with the [`Clone()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will only include the structure, and not the data

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Copy`, so something like this:

```
obj_dt_pdf = obj_dt.Copy();
```

instead of this:

```
obj_dt_pdf = obj_dt;
```

The [`Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method will copy both the structure **and** the data.